# cant load external js file in html

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have tried all answers available but none can solve my problem. I have a html page in which I am drawing svg using js. now I want to store this js in external file and call it (my html and js files are in same folder).
    `<script src="show1.js"></script>` on doing so, my internal js cannot find functions defined in external js and gives 'ReferenceError: DrawLine is not defined'. I even tried using alert in external js to check whether it was being loaded or not, but even alert is not working. is there any settings that i will have to check? kindly help.

My code is really huge. I am posting this snippet instead that shows the internal and external js.

```
 <head>
<script>
//only variables are declared
<script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="show1.js"></script> 
<script>  drawline(10,10,20,20,'black',4);  </script>
</body>
```

show1.js:

```
function drawline(x1,y1,x2,y2,c,w)
{
//do stuff
}
```

Note:these pages are part of django project, and so my html and js are stored in the template folder of the project.

Comment: Where u put ur script tag?? and when are u calling ur function?? Order matters

Comment: i have tried putting script in head as well as in body tag. i am calling the drawline function only after i load external js

Comment: Can u show us ur code??

Comment: code is too big. i am writting down the snippet where script is used: `<script src="show1.js"></script>
<script>drawline(10,10,20,20,'black',4); </script>`

Comment: can you show <head> to </head>

Comment: Do u want to execute the function in onload??

Comment: "but even alert is not working" — That means there is a problem with the external script (the second script is irrelevant). Given everything else, the most likely explanation is that you got a URL wrong. Use the developer tools in your browser. Use the Network tab. Check the script is loading correctly. (While you are at it, check the Console for error messages).

Comment: @manu, no. not on load

Comment: are you sure the javascript file is in the same folder as your html file?

Comment: @Kevin kloet, yes they are in same folder

Comment: could you share the folder structure image?

Comment: does it matter that this page is a part of a django project?

Comment: @user37886 — Maybe. Depends how the Django router is configured to deal with the code. If your HTML file is being treated as a static HTML file then it shouldn't make a difference. If your HTML file is being treated as a template, then the routing is very likely to not match up for the JS file.

Comment: @Quentin, yes i render my html files as templates. can you please throw more light on this matter

Comment: Not beyond the suggestion to read up on static file handling in Django.

Comment: @Quentin thank you for your suggestion. i have understood the problem now, everything makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the static file app in django to serve external static files: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

You can create a folder on you project to host your static assets (with the name static for example), then you need to configure your project to serve static files in the settings

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'path to your folder/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

then in your template:

```
   {% load staticfiles %}
    <head>
    <script>
    //only variables are declared
    <script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script src="{% static 'show1.js' %}"></script> 
    <script>  drawline(10,10,20,20,'black',4);  </script>
    </body>
```

in development mode, the runserver command will serve your static files. you may want to serve the files directly from the web server in production mode. also settings may vary depending on the django version, you can refer to the documentation of your version for further details.